# Perl - Remove duplicate from a referenced @array

Tags: perl, sorting, duplicates

If I've a perl array with following structure (Date, Time, User), sorted by user:

```
open my $fh, '<', $file;
while( <$fh> ) {
  my @lines = split /\n/;
  my ($user, $y, $m, $d, $time) = $lines[0] =~ /\A(\w);(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+);(\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+)/;   # Encapsulate values
  push @evts, { user => $user, date => "$y/$m/$d", time => $time};  # Array loader
} # This was missing.
close($fh);
my @by_usr = sort { $a->{user} cmp $b->{user} } @evts;
```

How could I remove duplicate entry from it, if it has the exactly same time?

```
$VAR1 = {
          'time' => '08:08:36.120',
          'date' => '2018/08/06',
          'user' => 'USER1'
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'time' => '08:08:36.120',
          'date' => '2018/08/06',
          'user' => 'USER1'
        };
...(and more)
```

I've try with unique function but it doesn't work:

```
sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}
my @unique_events = uniq (@by_usr);
```

I'm available for any clarifications.

Comment: I do not see the array. I only see `%hash` that have been saved into `scalar` ie `$var1` etc...

Comment: @Onyambu I've add my push value into array

Comment: @ThomasAnowez: I've added indentation to your example in an attempt to make it easier to follow. You're welcome, but please consider doing it yourself next time. Clear indentation is one of the best tools for understanding code and when you want a large group of strangers to read your code, then surely it's only polite to make it as easy as possible for them. Also, note that I've added what looks like a missing `}` to the code. Please feel free to remove it if my guess is wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAnowez: I'm puzzled by your use of `split /\n/` and `$lines[0]`. Unless you have changed `$/`, each line will only have a single newline character, which will be the last character in the string. If you want remove it, just use `chomp()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This answer is for eliminating complete duplicate hash references!

If you only want the *time* key to be unique, see [ysth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335229/1331451).

Your implementation of `uniq` only works if those references are pointing to the same memory. But likely they are not, they just contain the same value.

You need to look at the values inside each element and build your `uniq` that way. The easiest way is to simply concatenate all values in a known way. You can add a delimiter between the fields, like you would in a CSV export. You could also *hash* this with a digest algorithm (like [MD5](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5), which is in general discouraged but shouldn't have a high chance of collision here).

```
sub uniq {
  my %seen;
  grep {
    my $e = $_;
    my $key = join '___', map { $e->{$_}; } sort keys %$_;
    !$seen{$key}++
  } @_;
}
```

I picked `___` as a delimiter because that's unlikely to appear in your data. Since it takes the keys and sorts it, this can be used universally.

Also note that you can eliminate the duplicates before you sort by user. If you intend to sort by other columns as well, this will save you additional work. Depending on the number of lines of your input data, reducing will the size will in general be faster than sorting first.

Comment: Yours may be what they actually want, despite the question :)

Comment: Re "*This answer is for eliminating complete duplicate hash references!*", ....assuming all the hashes have the same keys. The following avoids that problem, and avoids the problems with using sentinel values: `my $key = pack '(J/a*)*', map { $_ => $e->{$_} } sort keys %$e;` Could also use `state $json = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->canonical; my $key = $json->encode($_);`

Answer (score 3):

You are only checking if the hash references (when stringified) are unique.  To check for unique times, just, well, do that.

```
grep !$seen{$_->{'time'}}++, @_;
```

simbabque's answer checks if any value is different, not just time (assuming all the hashes have the same keys and no values contain ___).

Answer (score 2):

- You have made this far harder than necessary by using a regex to parse your data: there is no need for anything more than a `split /;/`
- Please *indent* your code properly. You will find it much easier to work with, and it is only polite when you are asking others for help with it. As a result, your code won't even compile and I have had to fix it before working on the problem at hand
- You should also `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, and declare every variable as close as possible to its first point of use with `my`
- You should *always* check that an `open` call has succeeded, and invoke `die` on any error with the value of `$!` in the die string to say *why* it failed. It doesn't make sense to continue running most programs if the source of input data is unavailable

To make a list of unique entries, you can use the `uniq_by` function from the 
[`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) module.
This isn't a core module and is likely to need installing

Here's how I would write your code

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::UtilsBy 'uniq_by';

my $file = 'evts.txt';

my @evts;

{
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;

        my ( $user, $date, $time ) = split /;/;

        push @evts, {
            user => $user,
            date => $date,
            time => $time,
        };
    }
}

my @uniq = uniq_by { $_->{time} } @evts;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@uniq;
```

#### evts.txt

```
USER1;2018/08/06;08:08:36.120
USER1;2018/08/06;08:08:36.120
```

#### output

```
[
  { date => "2018/08/06", time => "08:08:36.120", user => "USER1" },
]
```